# Actionbar Icon are bigger than actionbar and are cropped

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-icons

I am using the sherlock's actionbar for my application. I am facing the weird issue in which in Samsung Note2, the icons on action bar are displayed bigger than the actionbar and are cropped.

On the galaxy ace, everything works perfectly.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have just one version in a drawable folder? If so, try putting different size images (18x18, 24x24, 36x36, 48x48) in the drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi folders instead. Android will automatically select the right size image to use depending on the density.

Comment: it is not the squared icon rather it is rectangle one!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some icons for action bar

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar

They will give you the exact size of icons you need for all screen resolutions and you wont face any problem.

In case you have your own icons, you can just keep the icons from icon pack as a guide for the size.